# Why shouldn't ngModels be directly bound to a service variable?

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I'm regularly binding `ngModel` directly to a **service variable** (consider value to be a public string variable or a getter function):

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="service.value">
```

Now I read more than once that this is not a recommended way and ngModels should be bound to component-/local variables only, but **never found an explanation for it**!

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The component class is the controller: it has to have the logic and the control on the template. Putting a value coming straight from the service, makes your controller weaker and less easy/obvious to debug. Your view is no more bound to its class directly

Comment: in angular-cli (I don't remember the version or if it's "solucioned") using a variable that not exist in the .ts give an error when you make ng build --prod.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `get` property and assign that to the `ngModel`

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value">
```

ts

```
get value(): string { // return type
   return this.service.value
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but what is the advantage of having a local getter function over directly binding it to the service variable, or a getter-function inside the service?

Comment: like @Vega mentioned it's much more easy to debug you code from the component. also, this prevents unnecessary HTML errors like 'can't access property called 'value'  in case the property is missing from the srvice'